# Tapestry5 non-editable text field

Tags: java, html, tapestry

I've been trying out Tapestry5 and I'm having a problem making a text field from a BeanEditForm non-editable. Does anyone know an annotation or something else that can do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a custom block for the property.

```
<t:beaneditform t:id="user">
   <p:age>
      <t:label for="age"/>${user.age}
   </p:age>
</t:beaneditform>
```

Comment: How can I make the value of the field non-editable there? I know I can make custom blocks, I've done that with radio buttons in the same app, but I haven't found a way to make the field value non-editable. I can't use the disabled attribute for the text field, because that way the field value will not be submitted with the form.

Comment: In my example, it is non-editable (there's no field). If you use the ValueEncoder provided by tapestry-hibernate, it will lookup the value from the database prior to updating the values and will leave the value as-is.